# translate c header file to delphi 2006

Tags: c, delphi

How to translate this declaration?

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *pCompletePlay)(LONG lvrPlayHandle, LONG lUserData);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the stackoverflow post editor to format your source code as *code*, making your post more readable.

Answer (score 2):

`type pCompletePlay = procedure( lvrPlayHandle, lUserData: longint ); stdcall;`

Answer (score 1):

In natural language, this declaration means: "Be *pCompletePlay* a pointer to a function which has two *long* parameters, using the stdcall calling convention", as the macro CALLBACK is defined as

```
#define CALLBACK    __stdcall
```

in windef.h.

The delphi declaration for this would be:

```
type
  pCompleteplay : procedure( lvrPlayHandle, lUserData : LongInt);stdcall;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special. pCompletePlay is just a type of function pointer which points to 
void (*)(LONG, LONG);

So, when you write:
pCompletePlay foo;   // foo is a function just like you declare.